# Upgrading iphone sdk to 3.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

This is the first time that I'm upgrading the iphone sdk and am wondering if there is anything else needed to use the upgraded version with xcode besides just installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the updated package and it indicated what would be upgraded, let it finish and then opened my projects and went on. In your projects you will have to make sure you are targeting the 3.0 OS though. And make sure your device is up to date as well(if using hardware for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, just install it, make sure you have 3.0 on your iphone or ipod touch tho :), this is for most cases anyway, here is a doc that might help you tho http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.0__final/iphone_os_3.0_sdk_readme.pdf